# How do I properly use chain populate method in my node application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a blog application using node.js and react. I am using MongoDB and would like to use the Mongoose `.populate` method to fetch data among collections. I have three collections so far: `Post`, `User` and `Category` collections. I have been able to use the `.populate()` method to get `username` from the `User Schema` model and point it to the `Post Schema` model. This way, users can make post and their username properly linked to them. Now, I want users to create category for the posts they create and I want that category to be associated with the specific post that the user made the post on. I have referenced the `Category Schema` model to the `Post` model and used the `populate()` method. After user creates post, the category doesn't show on the post. The category creation works well. But category is not populating. Seems I didn't do it rightly. Here is my code:

**Post Schema Model**

```js
     const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose
     const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

     const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
       
        title:{
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        description:{
            type: String,
            required: true, 
        },
        postPhoto:{
            type: String,
            required:false,
        },
       username:{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'User'
        },
        categories:{
           type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, //referenced Category Schema Model
            ref: 'Category"'
            
        },
       
    }, {timestamps: true}
    );
    //exporting this schema
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema); //the module name is "Post"
```

**Category Schema Model**

```js
    const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //import mongoose to be used
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

     const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
       catname:{
           type: String, 
            required: false,
       }
       
      }, {timestamps: true}
      );
     //exporting this schema
     module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema); //the module name is "Post"
```

**Post route**

```js
     router.get("/:id", async(req, res)=>{
     try{
        const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id).populate('username').populate(' categories')
         
       
        
        //const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id );
        
     
        res.status(200).json(post)

      }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err)
      }
      })
```

**Category route**

```js
    //creating catergory logic

    router.post("/", async (req, res) =>{
    const newCat = new Category(req.body);//we create a new category for the database
        
    try{
        const savedCategory = await newCat.save();//we need to try and catch the new category and  save it
        res.status(200).json(savedCategory)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a **typo** in your query. You have an extra `space` when populating categories.

Change this:

```
.populate(' categories')
```

with this:

```
.populate('categories')
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I have done that but it is not working still. I created a post in postman, there was no category section that I referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The Schema you have written has a slight problem,

the field name is categories which implies that it should be an array of category object IDs

for example the post can have "Tech", "Python" etc...

change the **categories field in the Post schema** like this

```
categories:[{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" }]
```

The reason you are not able to see the categories when you populate them in the GET route for post is because, the logic you have written is for **add new category** so this never says **which category is this post associated to**? You can add a new route for adding catgories to the post logic like this

```
//? Adding category to post logic
router.post("/:category_id/:post_id", async (req, res) =>{
    
 try{
    const {category_id, post_id} = req.params//? get the category Id 
                        //?and Post Id from the route params.

    //? Find the post you want to add the category 
    await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
     {_id:post_id},
     { $push: { categories: category_id } },
     {new:true},
    )
    res.status(200).json(savedCategory)
 }catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err)
 }
})
```

this logic will add the **categoryId into the categories field in the post**.

Now you query for post and populate the categories fields, you will get the categories the post is associated to

Comment: Oh, thanks for trying to help me. I was able to fix my issue way back days ago as I didn't get any help here until now that I checked. I simply changed the entire system. I deleted the category model. I used only post model along with the categories object section. I mapped into in react and fetched all categories. I used a javascript method to display only unique values on the side bar. This way, each post had their own categories and all unique value categories were displayed on sidebar. I will try your method when I want to implement comment features. I think it maybe handy there.